# Escaping the maze implementing DFS with usage of stack

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;
bool isValid(int &v, int &k, vector<vector<bool> > &a, vector<vector<bool> > &b)
{
    if(a[v][k] || k < 0 || v < 0 || k > a.size()-1 || v > a[0].size()-1 || b[v][k]) 
        return false;
    else 
        return true;    
}  
int main()
{
    cin.tie(NULL);
    int n,m;
    cin >> n >> m;
    vector<vector<bool > > prepreke(n, vector<bool> (m));
    vector<vector<bool> > posecenost(n, vector<bool> (m));
    stack<pair<int,int> > s;
    int v,k;
    cin >> v >> k;
    int x,y;
    cin >> x>> y;
    int a;
    cin >> a;
    for(int i = 0; i < a; i++)
    {
        int z,zz;
        cin >> z >> zz;
        prepreke[z][zz] = true;
    }
    s.push(make_pair(v,k));
    int pravac[4][2] = {{1,0}, {0,1}, {-1,0}, {0,-1}};
    while(!s.empty())
    {
        posecenost[v][k] = true;
        pair<int, int> p = s.top();
        
        if(p.first == x && p.second == y) {
            cout << "YES\n"; break; 
        }
        s.pop();
        
        for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            int vv = v; int kk = k;
            v += pravac[i][0];
            k += pravac[i][1];
            if(isValid(v,k,posecenost,prepreke))
            {
                s.push(make_pair(v,k));
                break;
            }
            v = vv;
            k = kk;
        }
    }
    if(s.empty()) cout << "NO\n";
    return 0;   
}
```

Input: Firstly we input the size of the matrix(NxM). Then we add the starting point, and the point where we want to go(end point). After that we enter the ammount of obstacles we want there to be(and as we inter >0, we input their x and y coordinates).

As I have explained the input, following the rest is easy. We add the starting point to the stack, then check if it is the endpoint. IF not, pop it, then we try to find one of the 4 paths that is not blocked/visited/stepping out of matrix.

The problem is, my program enters a FOR loop, find that we can go right and returns value 3221225477. I do not know what is the cause of this, yet I have tried putting everything everywhere.

Comment: Your `isValid` function doesn't look right. You should be checking the `v` and `k` indices are in a valid range _before_ you check `a[v][k]`. The size tests are also wrong. Try: `return v >= 0 && v < a.size() && k >= 0 && k < a[0].size() && !a[v][k] && !b[v][k];`

Comment: With the `break;` you seem to be assuming that there's only one valid direction that you can go in from a square - is that always the case?

Comment: You need to push all valid directions before you can continue with the "deepening".

Comment: @paddy, thank you. It is now working with your solution. Thank you a lot! Can you just post this as an answer, so the other ones who have the problem like I did will know what to do. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The `isValid` function is incorrect. Its *first* job must be to check that `v` and `k` are in the correct range. Right now, the first thing you do is test `a[v][k]`. But if either index is out-of-range, your program's behavior is undefined.

There's also the issue of your tests being backwards. `a` is indexed by `v`, and so `v` must be less than `a.size()` *not* `a[0].size()`. Likewise for `k`, which indexes `a[v]`. You simply mixed these up.

Let's also fix the function arguments. There's no need to pass the indices by reference, and also because `a` and `b` are not modified by this function, they should be const.

You can also do away with the `if` and just return a boolean.

```
// Note: a and b must have the same number of rows and columns
bool isValid(int v, int k, const vector<vector<bool>>& a, const vector<vector<bool>>& b)
{
    return v >= 0 && v < a.size()
        && k >= 0 && k < a[0].size()
        && !a[v][k]
        && !b[v][k];
}
```